# Query wrap in Knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

How do we wrap queries into groups on union?

I have this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
       (SELECT u1.* FROM `user` AS u1 WHERE user_email IS NOT NULL GROUP BY u1.key)
       UNION ALL
       (SELECT u2.* FROM `user` AS u2 WHERE user_email IS NULL)
) AS u ORDER BY u.id LIMIT 10
```

I was only able to do up to this:

```
knex.select('*').from('user').whereNotNull('email').groupBy('user.key')
.unionAll(function() {
  this.select('*').from('user as u2').whereNull('u2.email');
}, true)
```

But this would result to:

```
SELECT user.* FROM `user` WHERE user.email IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
(SELECT u2.* FROM `user` AS u2 WHERE email IS NULL)
GROUP BY user.key
```

which is a fail. Is there a way to do this? I need something like the first query because I need to retrieve sorted by id and paginated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How `unionAll` works in knex is quite problematic when combined with groupBy etc.

So I would go with `knex.raw` which is pretty powerful for any kind of complex query combining. Nice thing with knex raw is that you can use normal query builders for most of the parts and just write needed parts of the query as raw.

https://runkit.com/embed/905uidg7qdiw

Anyways this is one way to do it:

```
knex.from(
  knex.raw('? UNION ALL ? AS u', [
    knex('user').select('*').whereNotNull('user_email').groupBy('key'),
    knex('user').select('*').whereNull('user_email')
  ])
).orderBy('u.id').limit(10)
```